# R Shiny Download Handler Cant Read in other Output in the Server

Tags: r, download, server, shiny, dt

I am trying to use downloadHandler function in my R Shiny app and encounter an erorr.

Relevant bit of my **server.R:**

```
   shinyServer(function(input, output, process) {

    output$week1day1<-DT::renderDataTable({
      bench  <- input$bench.input
      squat  <- input$squat.input
      dl     <- input$dl.input

      ex1    <- input$Day1Main
      ex2    <- input$Day1Acc1
      ex3    <- input$Day1Acc2
      ex4    <- input$Day1Ass1
      ex5    <- input$Day1Ass2

      pr1    <- input$Week1Day1Ex1Pr/100
      pr2    <- input$Week1Day1Ex2Pr/100
      pr3    <- input$Week1Day1Ex3Pr/100
      w4     <- input$Week1Day1Ex4Pr
      w5     <- input$Week1Day1Ex5Pr

      if(grepl("Squat",ex1)){
      w1 <- pr1*squat
      }

      if(grepl("Bench",ex1)){
        w1 <- pr1*bench
      }

      if(grepl("Deadlift",ex1)){
        w1 <- pr1*dl
      }
      ###
      if(grepl("Squat",ex2)){
        w2 <- pr2*squat
      }

      if(grepl("Bench",ex2)){
        w2 <- pr2*bench
      }

      if(grepl("Deadlift",ex2)){
        w2 <- pr2*dl
      }
      ###
      if(grepl("Squat",ex3)){
        w3 <- pr3*squat
      }

      if(grepl("Bench",ex3)){
        w3 <- pr3*bench
      }

      if(grepl("Deadlift",ex3)){
        w3 <- pr3*dl
      }

      table1<-   data.frame(Exercise=c(ex1,ex2,ex3,ex4,ex5),
                 Sets=sets.week1,
                 Reps=reps.week1.day1,
                 Weight=c(w1,w2,w3,w4,w5))
                 DT::datatable(table1,options = list(bFilter=0, bSort=0, bProcessing=0, bPaginate=0, bInfo=0))

    })
output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
 filename <- paste("program", '.csv', sep=''),
 content  <- function(file) {
 write.csv(week1day1(), file)
  }
)

})
```

The relevant bit of my **ui.R:**

```
fluidRow(downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download'))
```

I get the following error:

```
could not find function "week1day1"
```

I would very much appreciate your help or any pointers in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimal working example of your server.R:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, process) {

week1day1<- reactive({
  bench  <- input$bench.input
  squat  <- input$squat.input
  dl     <- input$dl.input

  ex1    <- input$Day1Main
  ex2    <- input$Day1Acc1
  ex3    <- input$Day1Acc2
  ex4    <- input$Day1Ass1
  ex5    <- input$Day1Ass2

  pr1    <- input$Week1Day1Ex1Pr/100
  pr2    <- input$Week1Day1Ex2Pr/100
  pr3    <- input$Week1Day1Ex3Pr/100
  w4     <- input$Week1Day1Ex4Pr
  w5     <- input$Week1Day1Ex5Pr

  if(grepl("Squat",ex1)){
  w1 <- pr1*squat
  }

  if(grepl("Bench",ex1)){
    w1 <- pr1*bench
  }

  if(grepl("Deadlift",ex1)){
    w1 <- pr1*dl
  }
  ###
  if(grepl("Squat",ex2)){
    w2 <- pr2*squat
  }

  if(grepl("Bench",ex2)){
    w2 <- pr2*bench
  }

  if(grepl("Deadlift",ex2)){
    w2 <- pr2*dl
  }
  ###
  if(grepl("Squat",ex3)){
    w3 <- pr3*squat
  }

  if(grepl("Bench",ex3)){
    w3 <- pr3*bench
  }

  if(grepl("Deadlift",ex3)){
    w3 <- pr3*dl
  }

  table1<-   data.frame(Exercise=c(ex1,ex2,ex3,ex4,ex5),
             Sets=sets.week1,
             Reps=reps.week1.day1,
             Weight=c(w1,w2,w3,w4,w5))
          # delete these line and add the options part at the end of the renderDataTable below
          #   DT::datatable(table1,options = list(bFilter=0, bSort=0, bProcessing=0, bPaginate=0, bInfo=0))

})



output$week1day1Display<-DT::renderDataTable({
  return(week1day1())
}, options = list(bFilter=0, bSort=0, bProcessing=0, bPaginate=0, bInfo=0))   # options added

output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
 filename <- paste("program", '.csv', sep=''),
 content  <- function(file) {
 write.csv(week1day1(), file)      # here you had week1day1Display() instead of week1day1()
  }
)

})
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @guzbrush. I changed the code as suggested and now I have:
`output$week1day1Display<-DT::renderDataTable({
  return(week1day1())
})

output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
 filename <- paste("program", '.csv', sep=''),
 content  <- function(file) {
 write.csv(week1day1Display(), file)
  }
)`
However, changing week1day1 by week1day1Display in ui.R yields error, it cant find function week1day1. Any ideas?

Comment: You have to show all your code (the modified one), including ui.R, if you want more help.

Comment: I will update the code in the question to show it all just now. Can't thank you enough for looking into this. My ultimate goal is to be able to download all tables created in the server.R

Comment: There are too many characters in the code to post it here, so I added it  [here](https://gist.github.com/ivonavoroneckaja/4eec990f164bf40f8e024bf618771710)

Comment: I edited my answer from above and put a minimal working example (treating only the `week1day1` part) of `server.R` there. Your ui.R is ok.

Comment: It is working, thank you so much for taking your time to look into this for me!